# Eclipse debugger not working ( Skip breakpoints disabled )

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This is my first time running the debugger to check the values of my binary search tree but it seems to skip through all the debugger and it has a weird arrow beside the blue dot. By the way, the skip all breakpoints is disabled I made sure of it.

This is a short GIF of me running the program
https://gyazo.com/e236c1bd75ac746bf9982871ca847233

Added my other class

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private class Node{

    private T data;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    // left and right child do not have to nessary exist
    public Node ( T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null; 
    }}

    private Node root;
    private int count = 0;

    public void add( T data) {
        if ( isEmpty()) {
            root = new Node(data);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            insert(data, root);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {  
        return root == null;
    }

    public T getRoot()  {
        if ( root.data == null) {
            System.out.println("Root is empty");
            return null;
        }
        else {
        return  root.data;
    }}

    /*
     * Checking if the data is larger or lesser than the parent's data
     * If the data is smaller than the parent's data, node.left is created 
     * If the data is bigger than the parent's data, node.right is created
     */
    private void insert( T data, Node node) {

        /*
         * If 1st obj is less than the 2nd obj return a neg
         * if 1st obj is more than the 2nd obj return a pos
         * if equal return 0
         */
        int compare = data.compareTo(node.data);
        if ( compare < 1 ){
            if (node.left == null ) {
                node.left = new Node(data);

            }

        // make node.left if it is filled   
            else {
                insert(data, node.left);
            }
        }

        else {
            if ( node.right == null) {
                node.right = new Node(data);
            }
            else {
                insert( data, node.right);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return count;
    }

    private void removeInner( T data, Node node ) {

    Node temp;
    while ( node.data!=data) {
        int compare = data.compareTo(node.data);

        if ( compare < 1 ){
            node = node.left;
        }
        // make node.left if it is filled   
        if ( compare > 1 ){
            node = node.right;
            }

        if ( compare == 0) {
            node = null;
        }


        }


    }
```

}

[image]

Comment: Did you launch your application using Debug instead of Run?

Comment: @nitind yes, nothing really popped up

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling eclipse, not what you want to hear but could be the easiest route in the long run!

Comment: Which JRE are you running it with? Is Eclipse compiling the class or an external tool? Can you remove and reset the breakpoint?

Comment: @nitind
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211
jdk-14.0.1

Not sure what you meant by reset. I can remove it. I'm not exactly sure about the compile question but it should be compiling class. I'm not using any external tools

Comment: I just meant to set it again. Can you try debugging it with Java 8 or 11?

Comment: @nitind Tried JavaSE-11 jdk 11.0.7 didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one or more so-called **Trigger Point**s (decorated with a `T`) somewhere else from which one must be **hit first to activate** the other regular breakpoints. This can be seen by the regular **breakpoint in line 9** being decorated with a crossed-out `T`.

Solution: Delete or deactivate all Trigger Points (those decorated with `T`), e.g. in the *Breakpoints* view.

Comment: You mean there is some issue with the other class? That doesn't allow the code to run properly?

Comment: The trigger point option in my breakpoint properties is disabled. The only check box ticket is enabled

Comment: @Fenzox The breakpoint in line 9 will not become active, because the line where the Trigger Point is (which is in a different file), is not executed.

Comment: That function is activated, the size of the binary tree did increase and I'm not getting any errors

Comment: @Fenzox The breakpoint in line 9 is a regular breakpoint. But somewhere else (not in the shown file) there are one or more Trigger Points, that have to be deleted, deactivated or turned into regular breakpoints.

Comment: If you have one or more trigger points, the regular breakpoints will only become active after at least one trigger point has been hit. If you have one or more trigger points, the regular breakpoints are decorated with a crossed-out `T` (like your breakpoint in line 9) and Trigger Points are decorated with a `T` (not crossed-out).

Comment: @Fenzox There is a breakpoint. Somewhere in your code; NOT in this class, elsewhere - in code you haven't shown/pasted. This breakpoint is configured as a 'trigger' breakpoint. Trigger breakpoints are special: They disable all other breakpoints until they are hit. This feature stands separate from the 'disable all breakpoints' feature eclipse has (so the fact that that is off doesn't make a difference). You can find all breakpoints in the 'breakpoints' view in the debugger perspective (or go Window>Views>Breakpoints). Find it, and make it not-a-trigger or just remove that breakpoint.